# How does PatrickJMT do variation of parameters without the Wronskian?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, wronskian

In [this PatrickJMT video](https://youtu.be/X7pzGyfRx9A), he doesn't seem to use the Wronskian. He produces a set of equations and solves the example with them, but I'm not exactly sure where the equations come from.

Everywhere else I look seems to solve these kinds of problems using a Wronskian (and I think I have to, too, as I don't have the fundamental set of solutions given to me in the question like Patrick does).

Could anyone explain to me where the PatrickJMT method comes from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> $y_1,y_2$ are solutions of the differerntial equation:
> $$y''+py'+qy=0$$

Of course he used the Wronskian:
$$c'_1y_1+c'_2y_2=0$$
$$c'_1y'_1+c'_2y'_2=f$$
With matrix notation we have:
$$\pmatrix { y_1 & y_2 \\ y'_1 &y'_2}\pmatrix {c'_1 \\c'_2}=\pmatrix {0 \\ f}$$
$$\pmatrix {c'_1 \\c'_2}=\pmatrix { y_1 & y_2 \\ y'_1 &y'_2}^{-1}\pmatrix {0 \\ f}$$
$$\pmatrix {c'_1 \\c'_2}=\dfrac 1 W\pmatrix { y'_2 & -y_2 \\ -y'_1 &y_1}\pmatrix {0 \\ f}$$

Where $W$ is the Wronskian.

Comment: Thank you! I think I mostly just needed the reality check.

Comment: You're welcome. @Duck